# how to change format of object

Tags: angular, typescript

how to change format of object to date:

```
this.data 
// 0: {id:101, name='ram' createdDate='2022-06-23T08:14:54.607Z'}
   1: {id:102, name='Kris' createdDate='2022-05-21T11:36:32.289Z'}
```

I have to format the above date format like below:

```
 0: {id:101, name='ram' createdDate='23 jun 2022 14:54:60'}
   1: {id:102, name='Kris' createdDate='21 may 2022 36:32:12'}
```

I tried with Below code:

```
this.data.forEach(myData => { myData.createdDate = this.datepipe.transform(myData.createdDate,'dd mmm yyyy');
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `createdDate` attribute is already in ISO 8601 string format, it makes it easier to parse it as a date

```
this.data.forEach(myData => { myData.createdDate = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(myData.createdDate),'dd mmm yyyy');
```